# Adding a second or multiple device for a user django two factor authentication

Tags: django, two-factor-authentication

I am using [two-factor authentication](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) for a Django project. It is working fine but I want to implement few more features in my code. But I am unable to implement

**Expected Behavior:**

I want that a user has to face a 2F authentication prompt whenever the user logins from a new device. Also, I want to increase code validation time.

**Current Behavior:**
Currently, if a user logins for the first time, the user is shown an authentication prompt. But when the user logins from a new device, the user is not shown an authentication and easily logs in. But I want that the user has to face 2F from every new device. Also Whenever I change a step the validate code does not valid. For example, if I give step=60, then the validation code gets invalid. I am unable to increase the time for code validation.

I checked the TOTPDevice model in the database. It shows that now a new key is not generating for the new device.

I am using the below codes.

```
def get_user_totp_device(self, user, confirmed=None):
    """
    Gets user's time based one-time password devices
    """
    devices = devices_for_user(user, confirmed=confirmed)
    for device in devices:
        if isinstance(device, TOTPDevice):
            return device

class TOTPCreateView(APIView):
permission_classes = []

def post(self, request):
    username = request.data['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user_email = user.email
    user_device = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
    time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if not user.is_anonymous:
        device = get_user_totp_device(self, user)
        if not device:
            device = user.totpdevice_set.create(confirmed=False)
            secret_key = device.bin_key
            totp = pyotp.TOTP(base64.b32encode(secret_key))
            one_time_password = totp.now()
        url = device.config_url

        response_status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    else:
        url = {}
        response_status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

    return Response(url, status=response_status)

class TOTPVerifyView(APIView):
permission_classes = []

def post(self, request, token, format=None):
    username = request.data['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    device = get_user_totp_device(self, user)

    if not user.is_anonymous:
        device_registered = device.verify_token(token)
        if device_registered:
            if not device.confirmed:
                device.confirmed = True
                device.save()
            data = True
            response_status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        else:
            data = {'error': 'Verification code is not valid'}
            response_status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    else:
        data = False
        response_status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

    return Response(data, status=response_status)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to create a new table and store something like `machine_id` against that user in that table. Then you can create a `permission_class` or a `decorator` that will check if the user is on a new machine or the old one with the same `machine_id` as the `DB`. In that case, you will go to the rest of your view and return whatever. On the other hand, if the user is on a new machine, you can redirect them to the `2FA` page and then add that new machine in your DB against that user.

The other way I can think of is to stuff on the front end but not recommended you can make your frontend send you some validation creds from localstorage and if those creds are not present, you know that the user is either on a new device or visiting after a long time or whatever. In that case, you redirect them to the `2FA` page.

I hope I explained it well.